# Image not properly aligned

Tags: graphics, pstricks

In the beginning of a page the upper part of the image/picture is not seen while using pstricks on using latex

```
\begin{figure}[H] 
\centering 
\psscalebox{1 1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing. 
{ \begin{pspicture}(0,-4.63206)(10.815297,4.1163206) 
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](2.3220096,4.0177627) 
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](1.1098884,3.2177627) 
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](3.5098884,3.2177627) 
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](1.1098884,1.229884) 
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](3.5098884,1.229884) 
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](5.9220095,1.2177628) 
\end{pspicture} }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Please provide us with a concrete and complete minimal example that shows the issue. Such examples start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}` and can be compiled.

Comment: That is only possible if you are using the `standalone` document class or the clipping macros. However, show at least the code of the PSTricks part.

Comment: \begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\psscalebox{1 1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-4.63206)(10.815297,4.1163206)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](2.3220096,4.0177627)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](1.1098884,3.2177627)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](3.5098884,3.2177627)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](1.1098884,1.229884)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](3.5098884,1.229884)
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.2](5.9220095,1.2177628)


\end{pspicture}
}\end{figure}

Comment: There is no problem with your code. You have to create a complete example which shows the behaviour. Your code looks like an export from a graphic program. `\psscalebox{1 1}{..}` is also useless as `linecolor=black"